# How to remove an external resource from a jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I've tried hitting the minus button next to a resource, which hides it, but when I press "update" then refresh the page, the jsfiddle still contains the resource that I thought I removed.

(Maybe there's a bug in jsfiddle?)

For example, try forking https://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/32cnvse3, then try to remove any of the "external resources".

Asa workaround, I made a new fiddle then copied over all the code and added the desired external resources: https://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/apnax8va, but that means I have to go and update all previous URLs to point to the new fiddle.

```
// blah (ignore this)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - Forking the fiddle, removing the external resources and running it then works just fine...: https://jsfiddle.net/xngf6Lhc/1/

Comment: Yep, seems it has gotten fixed! Woo! I verified over and over when it wasn't working before, but now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's been fixed. It works now.